# Tornado: How to render response template from String?

Tags: python, tornado

For my request handler, my template is defined as string, not a file. I tried rendering with this, but received this error:

> File "c:\envs\pomo\lib\site-packages\tornado\template.py", line 365,
>   in _create_template
>       f = open(path, "rb")

```
SESSIONS_TEMPLATE = template.Template('''<html><body>

{{sessions}}    
</body></html>
''')

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):        
        self.render(SESSIONS_TEMPLATE.generate(sessions=response))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `self.finish` instead of `self.render`:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):        
        self.finish(SESSIONS_TEMPLATE.generate(sessions=response))
```

If you look at [render()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.render) method you will see it uses [render_string()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.render_string) method to generate string, inserts stuff like CSS and JS and then in the last line it uses [finish()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.finish) to actually create request. In your case all you have to do is that last call.